# Kotlin - Room Database - POJO - Entity class must be annotated with `@Entity`

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have this error when I use the code below, the goal is that I have a data class that contains a House object which is referred to the House entity which serves as parent. Additionally the entity ApartmentOptions should be the child entity of that House entity.
The data class Rent serves as a POJO, I did it like it was suggested in the Android documentation, but I still get the following error, What do I do wrong?:

Entity class must be annotated with `@Entity`:

```kotlin
@Entity
data class Rent(
    val id: Int,
    @Embedded val house: House,
    @Relation(parentColumn = "houseId", entityColumn = "apartmentId")
    val apartmentOptions: List<ApartmentOptions>
){
    @Ignore
    constructor(
        house : House, apartmentOptions: List< ApartmentOptions >
    ) : this(0, house, apartmentOptions)
}

@Entity
data class House(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val houseId: Int,
    val house: String,
) {
    @Ignore
    constructor(
        house: String,
    ) : this(0, house)
}

@Entity
data class ApartmentOptions(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val apartmentId: Int,
    val apartment: String,
    val isFree: Boolean
) {
    @Ignore
    constructor(
        apartment: String, isFree: Boolean
    ) : this(0, apartment, isFree)
}

@Dao
interface RentDao {
  @Insert
  suspend fun insertRent(rent: List<Rent>)
  @Transaction
  @Query("SELECT * FROM Rent")
  fun getRandomRent(): Flow<Rent>
}


@Database(
    entities = [
        Rent::class,
        House::class,
        ApartmentOptions::class
    ],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
```

Comment: `Rent` does not have the required `@Entity` annotation

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.
I have updated the code, and you will find my `@Database` Annotation at the end of it.
However, when I add the `@Entity` annotation to `Rent`, I encounter the following error message:
Entities cannot have relations.

Answer (score 3):

I am posting this as an answer because I cannot add a comment.

You can't use @Relationship in the entity. You have to use it in a data class that a DAO will return. Check this section of the docs:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many

> To define a one-to-many relationship, first create a class for the two entities.

In the sample code note how `UserWithPlaylists` is not an Entity but a class used in the method `getUsersWithPlaylists` inside the DAO class